# Error con el sudo apt update (ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, update

Soy nuevo en ubuntu, me pasé por temas de estudio (programación), el caso es que cuando hago el famoso "sudo apt update" me sale el siguiente error, no sé como puedo arreglarlo :

```
sudo apt update
[sudo] contraseña para usuario: 
Obj:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-x-swat/updates/ubuntu focal InRelease    
Obj:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Obj:3 http://packages.microsoft.com/repos/code stable InRelease                
Obj:4 https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian stable InRelease                           
Obj:5 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu focal InRelease                 
Ign:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu focal InRelease          
Ign:7 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 InRelease      
Obj:8 https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu focal/mongodb-org/4.4 Release        
Obj:9 http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu focal InRelease               
Err:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu focal Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.85 80]
Des:11 http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease [114 kB]
Des:13 http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease [101 kB]
Des:14 http://mirror.plusserver.com/ubuntu/ubuntu focal-security InRelease [109 kB]
Leyendo lista de paquetes... Hecho  
E: El repositorio «http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu focal Release» no tiene un fichero de Publicación.
N: No se puede actualizar de un repositorio como este de forma segura y por tanto está deshabilitado por omisión.
N: Vea la página de manual apt-secure(8) para los detalles sobre la creación de repositorios y la configuración de usuarios.
```

Agradezco cualquier ayuda.

Comment: Intenta esto: `sudo apt install ppa-purge` y luego esto: `sudo ppa-purge xorg-edgers` Parece que tu PPA no está actualizado con respecto a tu versión de Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero verifica que no es un repositorio oficial del sistema, si no es asi puedas probar a removerlo con `sudo add-apt-repository --remove ppa:nombre-ppa/ppa`

El repositorio parecer estar caído.

Answer (score 0):

Tuve un problema similar. Lo que hice fue eliminar dichos repositorios desde desde "/etc/apt/sources.list.d", así como también la líena de texto "sources.list".
Perdón si escaseo de información, soy bastante nuevo en el entorno :(